# Does $\int_a^b f(z)\ \overline{dz} = \int_a^b f(z)\ dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Question:**

**Attempted Answer:** Yes, for if $f = u + iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued functions, then we have that

$$
\int_a^b f(z)\ \overline{dz} = \overline{\int_a^b \overline{f(z)}\ dz} =\overline{ \int_a^b u(t)\ dt - i  v(t)\ dt}
$$

so that

$$
\int_a^b f(z)\ \overline{dz} =\overline{ \int_a^b u(t)\ dt + i\int_a^b - v(t)\ dt} = \overline{ \int_a^b u(t)\ dt - i\int_a^b  v(t)\ dt}
$$

and hence

$$
\int_a^b f(z)\ \overline{dz} = \int_a^b u(t)\ dt + i\int_a^b  v(t)\ dt = \int_a^b f(z)\ dz
$$

Is my reasoning correct?  If so, wouldn't my answer extend to any line integral along a horizontal arc in the complex plane?  That is, if we lifted $[a,b]$ to the straight line from say $a+z$ to $b+z$ (for $z \in \mathbb{C}$), then wouldn't $\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = \int_\gamma f(z)\ \overline{dz}$?

Comment: Your way of thinking is correct if $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Can you be clearer for the last question? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks, and I should have been clearer on my second question.  Let $\gamma = [a,b]$.  Then $\int_\gamma f\ dz = \int_a^b f\ dz$.  My question is if we let $\gamma_1 = [a+z, b+z]$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, do we have that $\int_{\gamma_1} f\ dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f\ \overline{dz}$.

Comment: What does $\overline{dz}$ mean? Is this supposed to mean $d\overline{z}$?

Comment: I think $u$ and $v$ still depend on the complex value $z$, so why do you think you end up with some real differential form $u(t)\,\mathrm dt$? You should use $\mathrm dz=\mathrm dx+i\mathrm dy$ and $\mathrm d\overline z = \mathrm dx-i\mathrm dy$.

Comment: Cameron and Christoph: As far as I knew, $dz$, $\overline{dz}$, and $d\overline{z}$ were just notational constructs.  Can somebody point me to a reference for what these terms mean in their own right?  For example, I'm not sure what is meant by the statement "$dz = dx + idy$".  All I know is Ahlfors' definition of $\int_\gamma f(z)\ \overline{dz} = \overline{\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}\ dz}$.

Comment: Also Christoph: this question seems to me to be distinct but related to that other question I asked.  If anything, I'm asking for the answer to a simpler case to help myself go back to the more challenging case.